# Can't find the login element in a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, authentication

I'm trying to login into a bank account using `selenuim`. I opened the web page and looked for the login element. I tried using it's "name" / "id" with no success, but I did manage to access it using `driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-trigger')`

Now, I'm inside the login trigger, and I can't get further.

When selecting the login box, I get this HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="username" autocomplete="off" name="username" maxlength="15" class="username form-control form-input" aria-label="קוד משתמש" aria-describedby="usernameError inputValidationMsg validationMsg serverErrorMsg serverErrorMsgTransmit msgCont" tabindex="1" placeholder="קוד משתמש" autofocus="">
```

So, I tried using `driver_trigger.find_element_by_id('username')` or `by_name('username')` but `selenuim` failed to find anything:

```
*** selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="username"]
*** selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="username"]
```

How can continue my way into my account?

*My end goal is to able to access various accounts (given username & password) and extract a few key details like the checking account, etc. I know each bank / webpage might have a different class names and such, so I'm really asking here HOW to find the right way to login, not WHAT IS THE WAY FOR THIS EXAMPLE*

---

With @KunduK - here is my script to login into an account:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


WEB_DRIVER_WAIT_TIME = 10

login_page = 'https://www.bankotsar.co.il/wps/portal/'
elem_id_username = 'username'
elem_id_password = 'password'
elem_id_login_frame = 'loginFrame'
elem_id_continue_login = 'continueBtn'


# init driver and open webpage
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(login_page)

# click the "login" button
login_trigger_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-trigger')
login_trigger_button.click()

# switch to login frame (to allow filling in username & password)
WebDriverWait(driver, WEB_DRIVER_WAIT_TIME).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, elem_id_login_frame)))

# fill in username & password
WebDriverWait(driver, WEB_DRIVER_WAIT_TIME).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, elem_id_username))).send_keys(username)
WebDriverWait(driver, WEB_DRIVER_WAIT_TIME).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, elem_id_password))).send_keys(password)

# click on the "continue" button
continue_button = driver.find_element_by_id(elem_id_continue_login)
continue_button.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are searching it is inside iframe. You need to switch it first in order to access the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it()`
Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "loginFrame")))   

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username"))).send_keys("TestUser")
```

You need to import following libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure from where you get the string "loginFrame" (couldn't find it in the webpage source). Also errors from the until function are empty messages :(

Comment: @CIsForCookies : please check the DOM snapshot.