# How to update driver location after button click changed url so the driver could find elements

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

*After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470727/cant-find-the-login-element-in-a-webpage/66471196?noredirect=1#comment117511752_66471196), I'm now stuck in getting further ahead...*

I clicked on a button, using:

```
   # click on the "continue" button                                                                                                                                                                          
   continue_button = driver.find_element_by_id(elem_id_continue_login)                                                                                                                                       
   continue_button.click()
```

and now I moved into a new webpage. I can see the driver was updated a few seconds after the click:

```
# click on the "continue" button                                                                                                                                                                                
print(driver.current_url)                                                                                                                                                                                       
continue_button = driver.find_element_by_id(elem_id_continue_login)                                                                                                                                             
continue_button.click()                                                                                                                                                                                         
# WebDriverWait(driver, WEB_DRIVER_WAIT_TIME).until(EC.new_window_is_opened((driver.current_window_handle)))                                                                                                    
import time; time.sleep(5)                                                                                                                                                                                      
print(driver.current_url) 

# Output: 
https://www.bankotsar.co.il/wps/portal/
https://online.bankotsar.co.il/wps/myportal/FibiMenu/Online
```

However, it seems the driver can't find elements in the new webpage. Each time I try to find element by id I get

```
*** selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Browsing context has been discarded
```

which, AFAIK means I'm trying to search in a dead window - i.e. the previous window.

- (1) How can I move my driver to the right location? (I tried using `new_window_is_opened` as you can see, but that didn't work for me). `time.sleep()` seems to help with the `driver.current_url` but not more than that. `driver.switch_to.active_element` helps - but only sometimes - not sure how and why...
- After the window is open, sometimes there is a pop-up that needs to be closed in order to continue. It has a close button + "X" button which I hope to find using "find_element_by_id" and then click on them.
- (2) Are pop-up handled differently than other things? (i.e. can I just find them and click, or another method should be called?)
- (3) How can I know if the pop-up really popped? It seems that it happens about 80% of the times, and I'm not sure why

Comment: After clicks on `continue` button is this opening a new browser window?

Comment: @KunduK posted my workaround

Comment: To move to new window
`driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])` and if you want to back to previous window `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])`

Comment: @Kunduk window_handles is a list with size 1 all over the script run

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around for (1), but it is very weird...

First, the url does change after I click the continue button, but the driver does not.

I found that running the following command does switch the driver, but it doesn't work out of the box `driver.switch_to.active_element`.

Before running this, I must run the following command `driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_url)`

However, this command raises `NoSuchWindowException`, so my workaround is this:

```
 try:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_url)                                                                                                                                                             
 except NoSuchWindowException:                                                                                                                                                                               
   pass                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 driver.switch_to.active_element
```

*Or use `contextlib.suppress`*